# Bug in PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ?

Tags: matrix, bugs, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays, expression-test

**Fixed in 10.1.0.**

**Exists in at least 9.0.1 -- 10.0.2.**

---

This seems like a bug in `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ` to me:

```
m = {
 { 2, -1}, 
 {-3,  2}
};

PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[m]
(* => False *)

PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ @ SparseArray[m]
(* => True *)
```

This is for version 9 and above; older versions (6-8) don't seem to be affected.

Comment: This matrix is not positive definite. It is positive-semidefinite: `{1, 1}.m.{1, 1} == 0`.  Note that the matrix is not Hermitian.  Positive definiteness is typically defined for Hermitian matrices, and for these it is sufficient to require the eigenvalues to be positive.  This is not true for generalizations to non-Hermitian matrices.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Extension_for_non_symmetric_matrices

Comment: The SparseArray result looks like a bug which you should report to WRI.

Comment: @Teake `HermitianMatrixQ @ m` returns `False`

Comment: @eldo Mathematica uses a generalized definition of positive definiteness though, e.g. `{{3, -1}, {-3, 2}}` is identified of positive definite despite not being symmetric.

Comment: @Szabolcs ah of course, you're completely right. I somehow forgot that it's not symmetric :).

Comment: @Szabolcs There seems to be a fair amount of confusion anyway, f.e. [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html)

Comment: @eldo Yes, you're right: the usual definition of positive definiteness is for Hermitian matrices only, so lots of things that math books mention about positive definite matrices tend to be not true once they're not Hermitian any more ...